# Как вывести даты создания

Tags: django

При создании айтема у меня автоматические добавляется дата создания. В `body` записывается сам айтем, он сохраняется в бд и затем выводится. А в `created_at` автоматически добавляется время создания. Мне нужно вывести все даты под которыми были созданы какие-либо айтемы в сортированом порядке.

-- models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
   body = models.TextField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

--views.py

```
    def all(request):
       date = Todo.objects.order_by('created_at')
       return render(request, 'todo/all.html', {'date':date})
```

В представлении я пытаюсь использовать `order_by` и вывожу это в `template`

--all.html

```
    {% for date in date %}
       <h1>{{ date.created_at }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
```

Затем я получаю такую ситуацию. Это практически то что мне нужно, но вывод зависит от количества айтемов под каждой датой, а мне нужно вывести просто дату один раз, то есть `Oct. 13,2018` и `Oct.14,2018`, каждую дату по одному разу, как добиться данного результата? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Todo.objects.values_list('created_at', flat=True).order_by('created_at')`

Comment: @floydya не помогло, выводит такой же результат что и у меня

Comment: Добавьте еще `.distinct('created_at')` в конец.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Todo.objects.values_list('created_at', flat=True).order_by('created_at').distinct('created_at')
```

но учитывайте что distinct(*field_names) только для PostgreSQL, в случае если у вас другая СУБД, у вас поднимется исключение django.db.utils.NotSupportedError